# Windows Driver Kit 8.1 standalone

Tags: windows, iso-image

I have been using [Windows Driver Kit 7.1](http://microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11800) (WDK).

Now I would like to upgrade to
[Windows Driver Kit 8.1](http://microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42273).

However I can only find exe installer, and I am looking for the
ISO / standalone / offline version. Where can I find such a link?

Comment: If it exists it would be located on Microsoft's website.  If you cannot find it, then it either exists and you should continue to look for it, or it does not exist.  I don't recall Microsoft releasing an offline installer for WDK 8.1 though. Since its intergrated in VS2013 its not shocking the download is so small.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using WDK to compile programs for Windows. However
[some projects](//github.com/XhmikosR/notepad2-mod/issues/89) are dropping support for WDK.

As a workaround I have created a [small version](//github.com/svnpenn/glade/tree/master/visual-studio) of Visual Studio for people wanting to compile Windows programs.

Answer (score 5):

**There is no ISO for the WDK available**. But there is a workaround to create your own ISO. Download the Installer, run it and select to download all files, instead of Installing it.

Now create an ISO of the downloaded data and you can use the ISO the next time you want to install the WDK. The same applies to the Windows SDK.